# "London Bridge is down" used as metaphor

Tags: usage, metaphors

Any Brit probably knows the meaning, now I (as a German) too. RIP Elizabeth II.

Has the phrase ever been used metaphorically ("the Queen is dead"; maybe by extension: "Anarchy will reign over Britain") in fiction of all kind? My suspicion is at least the lyrics of "Timebomb" by Chumbawamba (as "London Bridge is falling down" at the end of the song) might qualify.

Comment: An interesting question, but I'm not sure "has phrase X ever been used metaphorically in fiction" is a good fit for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is off topic for this site. I cannot identify of a suitable SE site for it. It is, however interesting and it would be nice if we could find a home for it somewhere.

Comment: With or without the death of Queen Elizabeth, *London is already burning*. In other words it's unusual to find "London bridge" as a synecdoche, you're more likely to find "10 Downing Street" or  "Whitehall"   to represent the government, and to a much lesser degree the people of the UK.

Comment: I didn't know the meaning (in this context) until a friend, who knows someone who works for the BBC, happened to mention it in a phone conversation this morning. However, the phrase comes from a well-known [nursery rhyme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-Y7Qi3fMs0). NB The video shows a representation of Tower Bridge, not London Bridge - a common error among non-Brits.

Comment: @KateBunting - in 1968 a bridge named London Bridge, built in 1830, and due for replacement, was sold by the City of London to the US company building Lake Havasu City in Arizona. A story goes that after all the carefully numbered stones were shipped there and reassembled, the company chiefs realised that the bridge with the raising parts is called Tower Bridge. I understand, though, that this is not true.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Yes, I'm familiar with that story. Apparently the purchaser denied that he had been expecting Tower Bridge.

Comment: @KateBunting Well, you'd think they would have prepared architect's drawings etc of the thing because they had to build an artificial lake with a narrow bit for the bridge to go across

Comment: I think it was the code name for part of the preparations for what would happen when the sovereign died but I cannot now find where I read about it.

Comment: @mdewey - Yes, the OP is presumably referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_London_Bridge), which my friend mentioned this morning (see my earlier comment).

Comment: @mdewey - the fact of the Operation London Bridge plans has been widely discussed in the UK media since at least Queen Elizabeth's eighties.

Comment: I take the comment of @Mari-LouA as an answer and humbly accept the closure.

Comment: @PeterJennings  Kate Buntings link and comments look like an answer to me. London Bridge is Down was the code used by the British press/mass media.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you will find that "London Bridge is down" is a code phrase used by the Royal household and senior members of the government to **prevent** the press and switchboard operators at the Palace from finding out about the death until a proper official announcement could be made. Presumably they didn't trust the switchboard operators not to immediately contact their favourite reporter / aunty should they overhear the news in clear text.

Comment: For all those not familiar with British nursery rhymes the phrase "London Bridge is falling down" comes from this song https://genius.com/Traditional-london-bridge-is-falling-down-annotated . Many other links are available including 3 versions on YouTube